Remove some characters from a JSON
I'm trying to remove the first 3 characters (they are always gonna be the same) from a JSON
Example
{
  "hotelnumber" : "1234",
  "hotel_code" : "HTL2233658"
}

and I want to get this (removing the "HTL")
{
  "hotelnumber" : "1234",
  "hotel_code" : "2233658"
}

I'd try a replace and a substring but no luck with it. Thanks in advance

Try this logic :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "count": "=size(@(1,hotel_code))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "hotel_code": "=substring(@(1,hotel_code),3,@(1,count))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "count": ""
    }
  }
]

In first operation we are calculating size of the field.
And in 2nd operation we will substring the field with 3(Since you want to remove first 3 char) till max size.
At last we will remove count field.
Hope this resolves your query.

works like a charm, thanks!

Great can you please accept the answer.
